# How do I stop IE x64 from telling me to install flash?

Tags: 64-bit, internet-explorer, flash

I use both the x86 and x64 versions of IE and since Adobe still can't get an x64 version of flash released every time I'm on a site that uses flash I get alerted to install it. It's really anoying now after 2-3 years of using a 64bit browser. Is there a way to stop IE from doing this short of installing the non-existant version of flash?

Comment: Two questions: a) Why are you still using IE? b) Why do you insist on using the 64-bit version? What does it give that the 32-bit one doesn't?

Comment: Let you use more than 2gb of RAM! That's... maybe 6 tabs with flash in them!

Comment: ahh, Phoshi, maybe 6 tabs but certainly NO flash in a x64 web browser! (not yet anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Short of using a 32bit browser with Flash, or some kind of magic Gresemonkey script that will remove the alerts, there is nothing you can do.

What I suggest is to install a 32 bit browser (Google Chrome is recommended, if not, Firefox) and then install the 32 bit Flash Player. That should work on a 64 bit operating system.